# Integrity constraint has been failed error

Tags: oracle

I have an issue with the foreign key constraint on the parent and the child table.I have below script to insert data from a remote database .Here is the create table scripts

```
        CREATE TABLE "S695_LANGUAGE" 
       (    "ID" NUMBER(5,0) GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1 CACHE 20 NOORDER  NOCYCLE  NOKEEP  NOSCALE , 
        "CODE" NVARCHAR2(5), 
        "DESCRIPTION" NVARCHAR2(50), 
        "IS_ACTIVE" NUMBER(1,0) DEFAULT 1
       ) ;
    
      CREATE TABLE "S695_TEXT_CONTENT" 
       (    "ID" NUMBER(19,0), 
        "TEXT_CONTENT_ID" NVARCHAR2(500)
       );
    
    
      CREATE TABLE "S695_TRANSLATIONS" 
       (    "ID" NUMBER(19,0) GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1 CACHE 20 NOORDER  NOCYCLE  NOKEEP  NOSCALE , 
        "TEXT_CONTENT_ID" NUMBER(19,0), 
        "LANGUAGE_ID" NUMBER(5,0), 
        "TRANSLATION" NVARCHAR2(500)
       ) 
    
      ALTER TABLE "S695_LANGUAGE" MODIFY ("ID" NOT NULL ENABLE);
      ALTER TABLE "S695_LANGUAGE" ADD CONSTRAINT "S695_LANGUAGE_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("ID");
    
    
      ALTER TABLE "S695_TEXT_CONTENT" ADD CONSTRAINT "S695_TEXT_CONTENT_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("ID");
      ALTER TABLE "S695_TRANSLATIONS" MODIFY ("ID" CONSTRAINT "S695_TRANSLATIONS_CK_ID_NOT_NULL" NOT NULL ENABLE);
      ALTER TABLE "S695_TRANSLATIONS" ADD CONSTRAINT "S695_TRANSLATIONS_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("ID");
      ALTER TABLE "S695_TRANSLATIONS" ADD CONSTRAINT "S695_TRANSLATIONS_TEXT_CONTENT_ID_FK" FOREIGN KEY ("TEXT_CONTENT_ID")
          REFERENCES "S695_TEXT_CONTENT" ("ID") ENABLE;
      ALTER TABLE "S695_TRANSLATIONS" ADD CONSTRAINT "S695_TRANSLATIONS_LANGUAGE_FK" FOREIGN KEY ("LANGUAGE_ID")
          REFERENCES "S695_LANGUAGE" ("ID") ENABLE;

Here the language table and translation table have a constraint relationship on language id field.
DECLARE
    v_seq_name   VARCHAR2(20);
    v_str        VARCHAR2(200);
    v_val        NUMBER;
     v_Nederlands_LanguageId NUMBER(5);
     v_French_LanguageId NUMBER(5);
     v_English_LanguageId NUMBER(5);
     v_Deutsch_LanguageId NUMBER(5);
     v_TextContent_Id NUMBER(19);
    V_MAX_TEXT_CONTENT_ID NUMBER(19);
BEGIN

    SELECT
        sequence_name
    INTO v_seq_name
    FROM
        user_tab_identity_cols@DBLINK1
    WHERE
        table_name = 'S695_LANGUAGE';

    v_str := 'select '
             || v_seq_name
             || '.nextval@DBLINK1 from dual';
    dbms_output.put_line('v_str = ' || v_str);
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_str
    INTO v_Nederlands_LanguageId;
    dbms_output.put_line('Value = ' || v_val);
    INSERT INTO s695_language@DBLINK1 (
        code,
        description,
        is_active
    ) VALUES (
        'NL',
        'NEDERLANDS',
        '1'
    );

    INSERT INTO s695_RESERVATION_language@DBLINK2 (
        id,
        code,
        description,
        is_active
    ) VALUES (
        v_Nederlands_LanguageId,
        'NL',
        'NEDERLANDS',
        '1'
    );

   
    -- Channel
   --commit;
   
    SELECT S695_TEXT_CONTENT_SEQ.NEXTVAL@DBLINK1 INTO v_TextContent_Id FROM DUAL;  
     
     INSERT INTO S695_TEXT_CONTENT@DBLINK1 (ID,TEXT_CONTENT_ID) VALUES(v_TextContent_Id,CONCAT(u'TextContent_',v_TextContent_Id));  
    
   select max(id)  into V_MAX_TEXT_CONTENT_ID from S695_TEXT_CONTENT@DBLINK1;
     INSERT INTO S695_RESERVATION_TEXT_CONTENT@DBLINK2 (ID,TEXT_CONTENT_ID) VALUES(V_MAX_TEXT_CONTENT_ID,CONCAT(u'TextContent_',V_MAX_TEXT_CONTENT_ID));  
     
    INSERT INTO S695_TRANSLATIONS@DBLINK1(TEXT_CONTENT_ID,LANGUAGE_ID,TRANSLATION) VALUES(V_MAX_TEXT_CONTENT_ID,v_Nederlands_LanguageId,u'MobileApp');
     INSERT INTO S695_RESERVATION_TRANSLATIONS@DBLINK2(TEXT_CONTENT_ID,LANGUAGE_ID,TRANSLATION) VALUES(V_MAX_TEXT_CONTENT_ID,v_Nederlands_LanguageId,u'MobileApp');
 
    INSERT INTO S695_CHANNEL@DBLINK1(CODE,DESCRIPTION,TEXT_CONTENT_ID,IS_ACTIVE) VALUES (u'MO', u'MobileApp', V_MAX_TEXT_CONTENT_ID, 1);
    INSERT INTO S695_RESERVATION_CHANNEL@DBLINK2  (CODE,DESCRIPTION,TEXT_CONTENT_ID,IS_ACTIVE) VALUES (u'MO', u'MobileApp', V_MAX_TEXT_CONTENT_ID, 1);
         commit;
 --rollback;
END;
/
```

Distributed update operation failed; rollback is required.
ORA-02291: Integrity constraint (S695_TRANSLATIONS_LANGUAGE_FK) has been violated - parent key not found.

it looks like the insertion to the language table is not committed and because of that it gives a foreign key constraint violated.(i think)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The foreign key that is being violated is:

```sql
ALTER TABLE "S695_TRANSLATIONS"
  ADD CONSTRAINT "S695_TRANSLATIONS_LANGUAGE_FK"
  FOREIGN KEY ("LANGUAGE_ID") REFERENCES "S695_LANGUAGE" ("ID") ENABLE;
```

When you use:

```
'select ' || v_seq_name || '.nextval@DBLINK1 from dual';
```

It will increment the current sequence value by 1 and return that value.

When you perform the `INSERT`:

```sql
INSERT INTO s695_language@DBLINK1 (code, description, is_active)
VALUES ('NL', 'NEDERLANDS', '1');
```

Then the `ID` column is auto-generated and it will increment the sequence number by another 1 and insert that new value.

When you then insert into the translations table you use the sequence value that was manually generated and that does **NOT** equal the value that was inserted into the table so you are trying to reference the wrong `id` value.

---

What you should do is to use `RETURNING ... INTO`:

```sql
DECLARE
   v_Nederlands_LanguageId NUMBER(5);
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO s695_language@DBLINK1 (code, description, is_active)
  VALUES ('NL', 'NEDERLANDS', '1')
  RETURNING id INTO v_Nederlands_LanguageId;

  INSERT INTO s695_RESERVATION_language@DBLINK2 (id, code, description, is_active)
  VALUES (v_Nederlands_LanguageId, 'NL', 'NEDERLANDS', '1');
END;
/
```

However, the `RETURNING ... INTO` clause may not be supported over DB links.

To solve that, you could create a procedure on the remote database and use `RETURNING ... INTO ...` inside the procedure so that you do not have to use DB links (except for calling the procedure).

---

Another alternative is to use:

```sql
'select ' || v_seq_name || '.currval@DBLINK1 from dual';
```

After inserting into the language table to get the current sequence value.

If you have a low-volume of inserts from a single user then that might work; however, if you have inserts from multiple users and they happen near simultaneously then you might find that both perform the `INSERT` into the language table at the same time and the sequence number increments twice and when they come to read the current value they both get the same sequence value. It is probably better to solve the problem in a robust way, and use `RETURNING ... INTO`, rather than using a way that only works in certain environments.

Comment: To solve that, you could create a procedure on the remote database and use RETURNING ... INTO ... inside the procedure so that you do not have to use DB links (except for calling the procedure). --- can you bit elaborate on this.without a dblink how will i push data...my case i  have one source database and 3 dblinksfor 3 destination dbs

Comment: @jubi Create one procedure on the DBLINK1 database to insert the `code`, `description` and `is_active` values into the `language` and `reservation_language` tables and return the `id` value and any other appropriate values (you can use `IN` and `OUT` parameters in the procedure to pass the values) and then used those `OUT` parameter(s) to manipulate the second and third DBs (either directly over DBLINKs or create procedures).